Expectation of average, conditional on terminal value
Silly question, but for some reason I'm a bit uncertain about this this trivial example perhaps:
I have the following simple BS model
$$
S_T = S_t \exp \left\{ -\frac12 \sigma^2 (T-t) + \sigma (W_T - W_t) \right \}
$$
I'd like to compute the following conditional expectation:
$$
E_0 \left[ \left. \int_0^T S_t dt\, \right| S_T \right]
$$
Can't I just write
$$
E_0 \left[ \left. \int_0^T S_t dt\, \right| S_T \right] = \int_0^T \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S_T \exp \left\{ \frac12 \sigma^2 (T-t) - z\sigma \sqrt{T-t}\right \} \phi(z) \, dz \, dt
$$
with
$$
\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 z^2} \enspace ?
$$

I'm afraid it's not this simple (but I am quite rusty with stocal so I can't remember the exact appraoch). The "problem" is we know the Brownian motion starts at $W_0 = 0$, and $W_T$ is also known. I believe the concept that you want to invoke is the Brownian bridge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge

@Rylan Yeah, it seemed to simple to me as well. Will read further.

My attempt at an answer (as I've said in the comments, I'm quite rusty... any corrections are appreciated)
We have $S_0 > 0$, and since we know $S_T$ we know $\sigma \sqrt{T-t}W_T = b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$.
Using the general case of Brownian bridge here, we have:
$$S_t | S_T = S_0e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2} + \frac{bt}{T} + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{(T-t)t}{T}}z}$$
And we want
$$E\Big(\int_0^T   S_0e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2} + \frac{bt}{T} + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{(T-t)t}{T}}z}dt\Big)$$
Using Fubini, this gives us
$$\int_0^TE\Big(   S_0e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2} + \frac{bt}{T} + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{(T-t)t}{T}}z}\Big)dt$$
We use the MGF of the normal to simplify the term in the expectation and we get
$$E\Big(   S_0e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2} + \frac{bt}{T} + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{(T-t)t}{T}}z}\Big) = S_0e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2} + \frac{bt}{T} + \frac{\sigma^2(T-t)t}{2T}}$$
meaning that the total term is
$$S_0\int_0^T e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2} + \frac{bt}{T} + \frac{\sigma^2(T-t)t}{2T}}dt$$
which Wolfram  gives me a nasty looking result for which contains error functions

+1 Error functions are good. I'm actually trying to re-derive a similar problem and result from a paper I saw, which also contains erf. I'll wait for other potential answers/corrections before/if accepting your answer. Thanks.

I accepted your answer. Just one question: shouldn't there also be a $\sigma$ multiplied with $bt/T$?

I think you’re right about that — will edit this soon
